# Xamarin Android Google map crashes on second load

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

The Google Map in `DialogFragment` and when, click a button in `MainActivity` to show `DialogFragment` twice my app crashes with such error:

> Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class fragment'

Anyone help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace HeyTeacher
{
    public class AddTeacherClass:DialogFragment, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        Button AddTeacherButton;
        EditText inputName, inputSurname, inputEmail, inputPhone, inputDescription;
        Spinner LevelSpinner, SubjectSpinner;
        Marker mrk;
        MarkerOptions mrkOptions;
        double latitute, longitude;
        string currentLevel, currentSubject;


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AddTeacher,container,false);
            AddTeacherButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddTeacherButton);
            SetUpMap();

            return view;
        }

        void SetUpMap()
        {
            if (mMap == null)
            {
                FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.mapAddTeacher).GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            mMap = googleMap;
            //current location camera
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(52.372769, 16.818880);
            CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
            mMap.MoveCamera(camera);
            mMap.MapClick += MMap_MapClick;
        }


}
```

Comment: That is view inflation error, check your xml file or design, it's not inflated  correctly